# Adobe Air - Captive runtime support

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Which version of Flash Professional or Flash Builder (Or any other software if available) supports publishing native installer AIR apps with captive runtime support?

(I would like to pack an AIR app as Windows .exe)

Thanks
Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash Builder 4.6 supports Captive Runtime and is due out on November 29th, I believe.

I don't believe Flash Pro will support it until the next version, assumed to be CS6.  I'm guessing that will be out in the first half of 2012 sometime.

If you can't wait you'll have to use the command line compilers.

Comment: So I need to download the AIR 3 SDK and run the command line, right? Is there something like a "command line generator" available?

Comment: There is no command line generater that I'm aware of; that's a neat idea though.  You'll have to read the docs, figure out which arguments you need and go from there.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot. That command line method seems not be so popular if there isn't even a generator for it. Maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Tooling; such as Flash Builder; just makes compiling things easier.  In this case, you're just a few weeks ahead of the curve; where Flash Builder will catch up to this AIR SDK feature.